# dynamically naming variables in R

Tags: r

I am trying to dynamically change the type of a variable in a loop. Right now I have the following line of code

```
assign(paste("contractrenewal",i, 
             "[,\"SContract Product ID from Object\"]",sep = ""), 
       as.character(paste("contractrenewal",i, 
                          "[,\"SContract Product ID from Object\"]", sep = "")))
```

Here, i runs from 1 to 18 and I have 18 dataframes that are as follows (`contractrenewal1`, `contractrenewal2`, ... , `contractrenewal18`). I have a column in each of these dataframes names `SContract Product ID from Object` that is of type int and I want it to be of character type.

The above code executes fine, but does not achieve what I am looking for. I have looked around and haven't been able to find anything like this

Comment: You are going about things in a very non-R like way. `assign()` can only be used with variable names (symbols). Something like `d[i]` is **not** a variable name. The `[]` is actually a function call. We can probably suggest a better way if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output.

Comment: [Use a list of data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick (and perhaps dirty) fix:

Follow [Gregor's link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/903061) and put all your data frames into a list.

(To reproduce your example I made my own list:)

```
cr.list <- list()
for (i in 1:18) {
  cr.list[[i]] <- data.frame("SContract Product ID from Object" = 
                               as.integer(c(123, 412))) 
}
```

Then you can loop through the list:

```
for (i in 1:18) {
  cr.list[[i]][, "SContract.Product.ID.from.Object"] <- 
    as.character(cr.list[[i]][, "SContract.Product.ID.from.Object"])
}
```

And now you can see that your variable is a `character` using `str(cr.list)`.